# Proof that the determinant of a matrix exponential equals the exponential of trace of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, exponentiation, matrix-exponential

The question arises from this tweet:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It was supposed to be a question, but I kept going...

I believe that the idea would be to use the diagonalization of the square matrix $M,$ such as

$$M= P\Lambda P^{-1}$$

where $$\Lambda =\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0&\cdots&0\\0&\lambda_2&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\cdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&\cdots&\cdots&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}$$

is the matrix of eigenvalues.

Now since

$$\begin{align}
e^M &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{M^n}{n!}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{P\Lambda^n P^{-1}}{n!}\\
&=  P\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Lambda^n }{n!}\right)P^{-1}\\
&=Pe^\Lambda P^{-1}
\end{align}$$

The determinant will be

$$\begin{align}
\det(e^M) & =\det( P) \det \left( e^\Lambda \right )\det \left( P^{-1}\right)\\
&= \det \left( e^\Lambda \right )\\
&= e^{\lambda_1} e^{\lambda_2}\cdots e^{\lambda_n}\\
&=e^{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2+\cdots +\lambda_n}
\end{align}$$

The right side of the equation would be

$$\begin{align}
e^{\text{Tr} (M)} & = e^{\text{Tr} \left({P\Lambda P^{-1}}\right)}\\
&=e^{\text{Tr} {(\Lambda)} }\\
&=e^{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2+\cdots +\lambda_n}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You almost have it. The thing still works if the matrix is not diagonalizable, you just work with the Jordan normal form instead of a diagonal matrix. I should emphasize that $J = D + N,$ where $DN=ND,$ $D$ is diagonal and $N$ is nilpotent. The fact that $D$ and $N$ commute is crucial